# Set the src value of an <img> tag with a knockout binding dynamically instead of on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to load thumbnails as I hover over a respective list item.

Below is the binding setup I am using

```
<div class="pageTitle" data-bind="text: ('Page ' + ($index() + 1)), value: page"></div>
     <div class="pagePreview">
         <img data-bind="attr: { src: $parents[1].GetThumbnailsOnHover($element, page, $parent.Id, $index()) }"></img>
     </div>
```

This will return the thumbnails, but it does so all at once on load.  This could potentially be an issue if I have 200+ list items.  I would prefer for it to only load as I hover over each one

I tried wrapping it in a function as follows:

```
<div class="pageTitle" data-bind="text: ('Page ' + ($index() + 1)), value: page"></div>
     <div class="pagePreview">
          <img data-bind="attr: { src: function() {$parents[1].GetThumbnailsOnHover($element, page, $parent.Id, $index()) } }"></img>
     </div>
```

But then it does not load any of the images, and instead sets the src to: `function() + image string`

Is there a trick I can use to delay the network call until I am actually hovering over the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a number of ways that you could go on this one like use the `event` binding with `mouseover` and place an observable to hold the source of each item. Then, populate that observable by calling your function on mouseover.

A slightly easier way that would not involve any viewmodel changes would be to simply prevent binding the children until the first hover.

You could use a custom binding for this purpose like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bindOnHover = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
       var bound;

        //set up a handler for mouseover
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "mouseover", function() {
            //apply bindings the first time
            if (!bound) {
                ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(context, element);                
                bound = true;
            }
        });

        //tell KO that we will handle binding the children
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

Sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/48PxT/

If you are using jQuery, then you could even use [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) rather than `ko.utils.registerEventHandler`, so that the handler is never fired again (not that the handler would cause perf issues).